# Using Delegates to assign images to a UIimageView

Tags: objective-c, button, delegates, uiimageview

How can one use a delegate to assign an image to a `UIImageView` located on a separate View controller linked by a button that will cause this action (the action of setting the images to the `UIImageview`).

Comment: Can you give more detail? Does the view controller with the image view create / push the view controller with the button, or is it the other way around?

Comment: better if you explain with example what you want to do...

Comment: I have a series of buttons that are all segued modally to another view controller. In this other view controller there are several UIimage views which i would like to set images to upon clicking one of the buttons. I tried using IBActions but it did not change the imageViews in the other view.

Comment: in the same way  you do with string & other object. return uiimage object with delegate to first controller & set image to image view.

Comment: @user3688257 i think you need to understand , how to pass data using delegate. check my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791199/can-i-use-to-pass-a-data-with-navigation-controller-back-button-in-xcode/23833710#23833710)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this to be question related with [Using a Button to change an Image in a UIimageView in a separate ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937599/using-a-button-to-change-an-image-in-a-uiimageview-in-a-separate-viewcontroller/23937943#23937943)

First define a protocol for defining the signature of method.

```
@protocol buttonDelegate <NSObject>

  -(void) changeImage:(UIImage *) img;

@end
```

Define your VC with Image View, conform and implement delegate. Assign delegate to self before presenting the button View Controller for e.g.:
.h

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController<buttonDelegate>

    @property UIImageView *imageView;
    @end
```

.m
        @implementation ViewController

```
    -(void) presentNewViewController
    {
        buttonViewController *childController = [[buttonViewController alloc] init];
        [childController setMyDelegate:self];
        [self presentViewController:childController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    -(void) changeImage:(UIImage *) img
    {
        [self.imageView setImage:img];
    }

    @end
```

In your button view controller call the delegate method on button click
.h

```
    @interface buttonViewController : UIViewController

    @property (nonatomic, assign) id<buttonDelegate> myDelegate;

    @end
```

.m

```
   @implementation buttonViewController

    -(IBAction)button1Clicked:(id)sender
    {
        [self.myDelegate changeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"]];
    }

    -(IBAction)button2Clicked:(id)sender
    {
        [self.myDelegate changeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"]];
    }

    -(IBAction)button3Clicked:(id)sender
    {
        [self.myDelegate changeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"]];
    }


    @end
```

Comment: Wow man, thanks a million! I tried something similar when i started reading about delegates but I was way off in my void procedure. Much Apppreciated!